# Typescript error in generic function with mapped types

Tags: typescript

I need to write a generic Typescript function which changes the property type of an object and assigns it a value.

First, I defined a new type which will change the types of the given properties:

```ts
type PropertyTypeMappedToNumber<T, K extends keyof T = never> = {
  [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? number : T[P];
}
```

I added a default `never` to the definition, since some model interfaces that I use in my code doesn't have these special properties which need to be changed, but I still want to wrap them in the above type to keep the codes and object treatment generic.

Then I tried it out:

```ts
interface A {
  a: string,
  b: boolean,
}

// Works as expected!
const x: PropertyTypeMappedToNumber<A, "a"> = {
  a: 100,
  b: false
}
```

Next, I need to write a mapper, which takes an input object, a list of property names and maps them to a number with assigning a value. Everything can be partial. Here is the implementation:

```ts
const mapperTo42 = <T, K extends keyof T>(data: Partial<T>, ...keys: K[]): Partial<PropertyTypeMappedToNumber<T, K>> => {
  const notMapped: Omit<Partial<T>, K> = data;
  const mapped: Partial<PropertyTypeMappedToNumber<T, K>> = {};
  for (const k of keys) {
    // ERROR: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'K extends K ? number : T[K]'.
    mapped[k] = 42;
  }
  return {...notMapped, ...mapped};
}
```

In the assignment expression I'm getting an error saying **`Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'K extends K ? number : T[K]'.`**.

I understand, that `K extends K` is not always true, given the complex situation with type system in JS/TS. But in our context it is somewhat known, those are the keys of an object. Is there a way to tell this to Typescript with some extra constraints/conditions or should I just use the "brute force" of type assertions?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Partial<PropertyTypeMappedToNumber<T, K>>`, you should be using `Record<K, number>` instead, since you don't need the definition of your complex type to define `mapped`:

```
const mapped: Record<K, number> = {};
```

then you won't get the unnecessary errors.